# issue with the arguments of a function pointer used in a function

Tags: c++

I have a function that act as an interator for array, where I pass function pointer to do calls of selected function, those functions receive one argument except for one who receives two arguments
my question is if there anyway to make this distinction without having to pass a dummy variable that wont be used or having to create another function pointer variable

```
//function that receives function pointers
int indexer(bool (Habits::*selector)(int counter, int y),std::string x="", int y=0);

//function acting as parameters

//argument dissonant function 
bool swapper(int counter, int stringIndex);
        //all other functions who only need counter argument where 'y' is needles
bool displayHabits(int counter, int y);
bool saveHabits(int counter,  int y);
bool removeHabit(int counter, int y);
bool openList(int counter,  int y);
bool clear(int counter ,  int y);
bool equal(int counter, int y);
```

is there any way in which i can have the above swapper function with two arguments and the others with only one within a same variable function pointer?

Comment: can you make it a [mcve]? In particular, how do you use the function pointer inside `indexer`?

Comment: No you cannot do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can overload `indexer`:

```
// for methods with 2 parameters
int indexer(bool (Habits::*selector)(int, int),std::string x="", int y=0);

// for methdos with 1 parameter
int indexer(bool (Habits::*selector)(int),std::string x="");
```